# Getting functions with the same signature from a namespace and iterating over them in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

I got a (potentially) unlimited set of functions with the same signature, which all live in the same namespace:

```
namespace cost_functions
{
   int calculate_cost_1(std::vector<double> waypoints, double time);
   int calculate_cost_2(std::vector<double> waypoints, double time);
   ...
   int calculate_cost_n(std::vector<double> waypoints, double time);
}
```

And I want to get these functions into a vector dynamically, such that I can iterate over them in the following way:

```
auto waypoints = get_waypoints();
auto t = get_time();
auto cost_functions = get_all_cost_functions();
auto total_cost = 0;
for(cost_function:cost_functions)
{
   total_cost += cost_function();
}
```

How do I have to implement `get_all_cost_functions()`? Is there some kind of reflexion in C++14?

Comment: If you're lucky, reflection will come in C++20, sorry.

Comment: So there is no way of doing this in C++14? What if I don't want to load the functions dynamically? How would get_all_cost_functions() look like? Can I just return a vector containing all functions, and how would this vector be implemented?

Comment: @user1934212 No, there's no way to do that. You can implement such vector like `std::vector<std::function<int (std::vector<double>,double)>> funcs;`

Comment: @user1934212 You might be able to abuse the preprocessor though.

Comment: "Function Signature. A function's signature includes the function's name and the number, order and type of its formal parameters. Two overloaded functions must not have the same signature. The return value is not part of a function's signature."   Since each of your functions has a unique name, they each have a unique signature.  Note: I have found some contradictions of this definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some kind of reflexion in C++14?

No there is no reflection.

> How do I have to implement `get_all_cost_functions()`?

Something along the lines of

```
const std::vector<std::function<int (std::vector<double>,double)>>& 
    get_all_cost_functions() {
        static std::vector<std::function<int (std::vector<double>,double)>> funcs {
            calculate_cost_1 ,
            calculate_cost_2 ,
            calculate_cost_3 ,
            calculate_cost_4 ,
            calculate_cost_5 ,
            calculate_cost_6 ,
            // 
            calculate_cost_xx ,
            };
        return funcs;
    }
```

---

Here's another idea (probably easier to manage when additional cost calculation functions should be added in future):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

namespace cost_functions
{

    class CostFunctionRegistrar {
    public:
    typedef std::function<int (std::vector<double>,double)> CostCalulationFunc;

         CostFunctionRegistrar(std::function<int (std::vector<double>,double)> func) {
             allCostCalculationFuncs.push_back(func);
         }
         static const std::vector<CostCalulationFunc>& get_all_cost_functions() {
             return allCostCalculationFuncs;
         }
    private:
         static std::vector<CostCalulationFunc> allCostCalculationFuncs;
    };

    std::vector<CostFunctionRegistrar::CostCalulationFunc> CostFunctionRegistrar::allCostCalculationFuncs;

   int calculate_cost_1(std::vector<double> waypoints, double time) {
       std::cout << "calculate_cost_1" << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
   static CostFunctionRegistrar r1(calculate_cost_1);

   int calculate_cost_2(std::vector<double> waypoints, double time) {
       std::cout << "calculate_cost_2" << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
   static CostFunctionRegistrar r2(calculate_cost_2);

   int calculate_cost_n(std::vector<double> waypoints, double time) {
       std::cout << "calculate_cost_n" << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
   static CostFunctionRegistrar rn(calculate_cost_n);
}


int main()
{
    for(auto cost_calc : cost_functions::CostFunctionRegistrar::get_all_cost_functions()) {
        std::vector<double> waypoints;
        double time = 0;
        cost_calc(waypoints,time);
    }
}
```

See the live demo working [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd5f4e8640fa1afd).

Comment: `std::function` is a mighty overkill for this task. Just use function pointers.

Comment: @Quentin You say that as long not anyone might get the great idea to implement a bunch of `calculate_cost_YXZ()` functions with lambdas.